# Generate point cloud from depth image

Tags: python, image, point-clouds, depth, projection-matrix

I am trying to convert a depth image (RGBD) into a 3d point cloud. The solution I am currently using is taken from [this post](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/79032/generating-a-3d-point-cloud) where:

- `cx` = image center height
- `cy` = image center width
- `fx` and `fy` = `250`, chosen by iterating through a few options

The depth measurements have been taken from a pin hole camera and the point cloud is projecting away from the centre (example images below). Can anyone help me understand why and how I can solve this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 20):

You may easily solve this using `open3d` package. Install it using `sudo pip install -U open3d-python` (not just `open3d` -- that's another package).

Once installed:

```
import open3d as o3d

rgbd = o3d.geometry.RGBDImage.create_from_color_and_depth(color, depth, convert_rgb_to_intensity = False)
pcd = o3d.geometry.PointCloud.create_from_rgbd_image(rgbd, pinhole_camera_intrinsic)

# flip the orientation, so it looks upright, not upside-down
pcd.transform([[1,0,0,0],[0,-1,0,0],[0,0,-1,0],[0,0,0,1]])

draw_geometries([pcd])    # visualize the point cloud
```

The above code assumes you have your color image in `color` and depth image in `depth`, check the samples coming with `open3d` for more information.

If you have your own camera intrinsic, you may replace `pinhole_camera_intrinsic` with those, but for the test run, the pinhole camera works more or less fine.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion @Lenik.

The output of this gives me a sliced point cloud (https://ibb.co/yy4F94b) do you know why?

Comment: @LloydRayner if you find my answer useful, you may upvote and/or accept it, why your point cloud look "sliced" -- I don't know, it's unlikely to be a problem of `open3d` package -- I use that quite a lot. Probably taking a look at your depth data might help, especially something like plotting number of points versus the distance -- it might show you some "missing" depth regions or other irregularities.

Comment: I have a question about how to load Image and Depth data. In function "create_rgbd_image_from_color_and_depth", input arguments are "color" and "depth". Could you explain how to load image? Do you use OpenCV or PIL Image for this purpose? I really appreciate it if you could share the whole code.

Comment: @Mohammad You can load the images from file with `depth = o3d.io.read_image(filename)`. You can also convert numpy images to o3d as mentioned [here](https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D/issues/957#issuecomment-491571979), but for me that sometimes doesn't work (for whatever reason, I don't know).

Comment: The package open3d-python did not work for me, but open3d seems to provide the desired functionality.