How do I convert a 2D coordinates to 3D real world coordinates using open3d python?
I don't want to create a 3D model. I just want to convert a given point in an image to its corresponding 3D coordinate.
While researching I found deep learning models that calculate the depth which will be useful to find the 3D coordinates. But I am understand how to access the depth values after using the DL model on the video. The video is being generated and saved but I don't know where to access the depth values.
After that I came across open3D which has an method which can help convert a single point to a 3D point but it requires "depth", "intrinsic parameters" and "extrinsic parameters".
open3d.geometry.create_point_cloud_from_depth_image(depth, intrinsic)

My question is:

How do I find intrinsic and extrinsic parameters using open3D or any other way?

Apart from open3D or anything, how do I find instrinsic, extrinsic and depth values in any other way?

Are there any good books/tutorials which explains this?



This is a very broad question. A good start would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59590200/generate-point-cloud-from-depth-image
